# Select left 4 characters without duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have a database table named `monthly`. One of the column names is `month`.

Inside `month`, there is these few datas - `201601, 201602, 201501, 201502`.

Now what I want to do is to get the first 4 characters from the LEFT (basically trying to just take the year value out) and display it without duplicates.

This is the mySQL code that I tried:

```
SELECT LEFT(month,4) from monthly
```

This however is wrong. Can I know how do I write the query to get only the first 4 characters without any duplicate value?

So for this, the result should be just `2015, 2016`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(month,4) AS `Year` 
FROM monthly
```